# Apple and Internet Explorer

Tags: macos, internet-explorer

Someone smart who I know just mentioned that the idea of downloading Internet Explorer onto a Mac seems counterintuitive, even though it might make sense to do since Safari seems to have problems on a certain site for a project we're working on. I'm just wondering why this is and would greatly appreciate any clarification. In summary:

```
    Why does it not make sense to download Internet Explorer onto a Mac?
```

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a serious answer:

The best way to test something with IE7 for Windows is to use IE7 for Windows. Just because you have a Mac doesn't mean you can't do that. You can run Windows through BootCamp. Or buy a used $99 Windows box and borrow the Mac's keyboard/mouse/etc. Of course it's much more convenient, and almost certainly good enough, to run Windows in a VM under OS X via Parallels, VMware, etc. Wine will mostly work, but it can be fiddly to configure, and may crash and/or have visual glitches that don't happen with real Windows; if you really want to get serious about that you may want to look at Crossover.

But the next best way to test IE7 for Windows is actually Opera. Of course in the case of bugs and quirks that are still present in later versions of IE, they'll do a perfect job of emulating IE7, but for bugs that were fixed, that's not a particularly important focus. Opera, on the other hand, works hard to be able to emulate the quirks of all of the important browsers. Make sure to enable IE quirks mode, and set the user agent to pretend to be IE7 for Windows, and you should be golden.

But for the question you actually asked, there is no blanket answer to this that could possibly be correct. There are many reasons it may not make sense to download Internet Explorer onto a Mac, and also many reasons why it might.

- You can't run IE for Mac on any modern Mac.

  - If you have an ancient Mac, and it's running 10.2 or 10.3 rather than 10.4, it already has IE (and if you want to reinstall it, it's part of the OS X install), so there's no reason to download IE.
  - You also can't legally download IE for Mac from anywhere anymore (except as part of old versions of OS X).
  - And IE for Mac is actually far less like IE7 for Windows than any modern browser is.
- You can't run IE for Windows (or Pocket IE for Windows Mobile) on Mac OS X.

  - But you can run it under wine.
  - And you can run it in a virtual machine running Windows.

    - Except that Windows comes with Internet Explorer, so there's no reason to download it.
    - Unless your Windows comes with an older version and you want to update it.
  - And a Mac can run Windows instead of OS X if you want (e.g., via BootCamp).

    - Same caveats as with a VM.
  - And there may be other reasons to download it other than running it.

    - If your Mac has access to a fast internet connection and your Windows box doesn't, you might want to download the installer on the Mac to copy it locally to Windows.
    - Sometimes you just want to use up internet bandwidth.
    - Maybe you're testing your download speeds.
    - Maybe you're about to dump your boyfriend, and first you want to run him $300 over his monthly bandwidth limits.
    - Someone at Microsoft might find it entertaining when they notice in the logs that you've downloaded IE on a Mac, and it's always nice to bring a smile to a stranger's face.

Answer (score 2):

The last version of Internet Explorer for Macintosh was 5.2, out in 2003. It wouldn't even run on a modern machine. The build is just not compatible.

If you want to try a different browser, both Chrome and Firefox run on OSX.

To run internet explorer on the Mac, you'd need to use some sort virtualization, running Windows either through Boot Camp or Parallels.

Comment: Chrome/Firefox sadly don't emulate IE. Or maybe that's a good thing.

Comment: There are MSIE VMs available for VirtualBox which do not require purchasing a Windows license (see answer posted this page)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do it because I'm developing software and the client wants to have it styled for IE 7 (the version they have on all their machines).

If I had my druthers, I'd run it under virtualization (e.g., VMWare), but I've misplaced my old XP CDs, so I settled for Wine (which works 'okay', but crashes from time-to-time).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using VirtualBox which would enable you to run MSIE on your Mac directly:
  https://www.virtualbox.org/

...and here are the VMs for MSIE 6, 7, 8 and 9:
  https://github.com/xdissent/ievms

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not a good idea to install Internet Explorer for Mac. It simply doesn't work properly as it was discontinued by Microsoft in 2005. However, if you have to use it to view certain websites that will only work in IE, this is the easiest way to download and install it for Mac: http://machow2.com/download-internet-explorer-for-mac/